# I'm trying to set up an if statement in React-native, but it wont work properly

Tags: react-native, if-statement, logic

I have a function if statement set up to check if one user-input number is bigger than another user-input number, and then subtract the bigger number from the smaller one to create the answer to the problem. But whenever I run the code, sometimes it will work fine, but usually, it will only ever select the first number as the bigger one.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

import { AppRegistry, Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default class App extends Component {

```
state = {
    num1: 0,
    num2: 0,
    num3: 0,
    message: ' ',
};

subtractSmallerNumber = () => {
    if (this.state.num1 > this.state.num2) {
        this.setState({ 
            num3: (this.state.num1 - this.state.num2),
            message: 'num1 is bigger',
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({ 
            num3: (this.state.num2 - this.state.num1),
            message: 'num2 is bigger',
        })
    }
}
```

I tried rewriting the code but I'm not sure if it's a syntax error. I'm not really sure what to do because I just started working with react native and I don't know a lot yet, but I wasn't sure what to look up online.

Answer (score 0):

It would be beneficial to see the full code as its unclear if the error could be happening within the function you have provided. Also what are the default state values (if any)?

I would hazard a guess that your numbers are probably being evaluated as strings, so it could do with it being cast as a `Number`. The code you provided can be cleaned up without the use of an if/else statement too with the use of a ternary operator, so your function only every relies on 1 useState, like so:

```
subtractSmallerNumber = () => {
  const { num1, num2 } = this.state;
  
  const isBigger = Number(num1) > Number(num2);
  
  this.setState({
    num3: isBigger ? Number(num1) - Number(num2) : Number(num2) - Number(num1),
    message: `${isBigger ? 'num1' : 'num2'} is bigger`,
  });
};
```

Comment: I added the code from the beginning where I established the numbers. I tried putting them in with and without quotes but either way the code acts the same way.